# laravel sql server connection not working

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, database-connection

I'm new to the PHP framework Laravel and I wanted to connect it with my database. What I have is:

- sqlsrv as default database connection

[image]

- add sqlsrv configuration

[image]

- Change the .env file

[image]

- Added the PHP driver to connect with SQL Server

But nothing is working :( The error I get is:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server (2)

Anyone who knows how to solve this?
I tried MySQL and that connection worked btw ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel with mssql (sqlsrv) not connecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443371/laravel-with-mssql-sqlsrv-not-connecting)

Comment: I had that problem first @rajathans, but I solved that one. Now it still doesn't work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel connection MSSqL server works with cli, but not in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352961/laravel-connection-mssql-server-works-with-cli-but-not-in-browser)

Comment: Having perhaps similar issues with sqlsrv, both on two Linux machines and a Win 10 box. What's odd is that I have the drivers installed, and can hit the database with PHP queries, but "php artisan migrate" comes back with "could not find driver" and of course I cant use any models. This is with Laravel 7.

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > TCP/IP > Properties> TCP Port check if it is set to 1433. Then restart services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I can check the TCP port in "IP adresses" but there it isn't set at all. And it has different IP's, IP1 - IP11. I can set the TCP port for every IP address but do you think that will work?

Answer (score -1):

If MySQL is working and not mssql, I am assuming PHP_dblib module has not been installed.
The bellow code will display installed modules.