# Laravel connection MSSqL server works with cli, but not in browser

Tags: php, sql-server, driver, laravel-5.4

After installing the `dll's` to use with MSSqL server, the command `php artisan migrate` ran correctly and the tables were made in the `db`. So I thought the connection would work for this application.

I then used the command `php artisan make:auth` (which doesn't use the db connection) to scaffold the authentication files.

Now when I try to register anyone I get errors:

> **PDOExeption (1/2)**
>
> Could not find driver

and

> **PDOExeption (2/2)**
>
> Could not find driver (select count(*) from .....

Now I tried to see if using the `cli` commands still work and both `php artisan migrate:rollback` and `php artisan migrate` still work.

Environment:
Windows 7 with xampp installed.
Versions: Laravel 5.4, php 7.1

Not that it matters but here are parts of my `.env` and `database.php` files:

```
`database.php`
        'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '10.0.0.40'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sqlcon'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

`.env`
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=10.0.0.40
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=sqlcon
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

So how come the `cli` commands work and the browser don't?

Doesn't laravel use the same config for both `cli` and browser connections?

---

Update: added some extra info

> C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlcon>php --ini
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Used [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/edit-laravels-out-of-the-box-phpini) to show my php configuration and it shows:

> Loaded Configuration File C:\xampp\php\php.ini

The php -m command shows:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlcon>php -m
>
> [PHP Modules]
>
> bcmath
>
> ...(some others)
>
> pdo_mysql
>
> pdo_sqlite
>
> pdo_sqlsrv (this one is enabled)
>
> Phar
>
> ...
>
> [Zend Modules]

According to `php -m` the `pdo_sqlsrv` is enabled, but I can't find any reference to it in the `phpinfo` page.

Comment: Are cli and webserver using the same `php.ini`?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. How can I find out? Remember I'm using laravel (so I think they should both use the same) and afaik I only have one `php.ini`

Comment: You can try to run `php -m` on cli and create some route with `phpinfo()` to confirm if extension is loaded for both

Comment: I think they don't use the same or the webserver cannot find the driver, see my edits.

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` says what `php.ini` xampp is using? Has a long time I dont use xampp, but I remind that is another file for apache

Comment: they both use the same as far as I can see. `Loaded Configuration File C:\xampp\php\php.ini` is from `phpinfo()` and `Loaded Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini` is from cli command `php --ini`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145798/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-davejal).

Comment: I had same issue. I'll post what I have done for solving that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What I thought had fixed the problem

When installing the driver in `php.ini` I used the following line as this was the name of the file in the extension directory (`extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`):

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

Changing both the name of the file in this directory and the reference to it in the `php.ini` file and restarting `apache` solved the problem.

So now the file is `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` and the reference is:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
```

### What actually fixed the problem

Installing [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) after downloading the `dlls` and making the change to `php.ini`.

Don't forget to restart `apache`.

Comment: Actually, restarting apache solved the problem when PHP is running as a apache module according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892408/2099835

Comment: @gmsantos I retried it again and now it works with php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll, so this it not the reason it was resolved. It was resolved because I installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 last night

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I have solved as follow (WAMP):

---

### 1. Download Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server

You should download following 2 .dll files.

- **PHP PDO SQL Server Driver** 
  ex.:- php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
- **PHP SQL Server Driver**
  ex.:- php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

You have to concern about:

- Operating System.
- Operating System version (32bit/64bit).
- PHP version.
- PHP Thread Safety (ts/nts).

(My Case: Windows 7 64bit / PHP 7 / Thread Safe -> _7_ts_x64)

---

### 2. Install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server in WAMP

Put those downloaded 2 .dll files into **wamp64\bin\php\php*\ext**

---

### 3. Configure Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server in WAMP

Type following code after default extensions:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

in following files: 
**wamp64\bin\apache\apache*\bin\php.ini 

wamp64\bin\php\php*\php.ini 

wamp64\bin\php\php*\phpForApache.ini**

---

### 4. Restart WAMP